# Yii not diagnosis route when first same started

Tags: php, yii, yii1.x, yii-routing

Why my yii 1 route not diagnosis when first same started.
I have two same route in first characters and yii not diagnosis second route in route array list :

first route:

```
array('/shop/order/view', 'pattern' => '/api/v1/orders/<orderId>', 'verb' => 'GET'),
```

second route:

```
array('/shop/order/statistics', 'pattern' => '/api/v1/orders/statistics', 'verb' => 'GET'),
```

This is my two routes but when call second route first route called and not get in statistics function.

Thank you for your help.

my yii framework is yii1. I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: first route : array('/shop/order/view', 'pattern' => '/api/v1/orders/<order_id>', 'verb' => 'GET')